# Referencing a worksheet in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm working on a project for work, and am trying to color bars inside a bar graph. Multiple worksheets with different charts are made, but they all follow the same color scheme. I'm very new to VB (just picked it up 2 days ago) and I have what will probably be a basic question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a separate function to color each chart, but I want to condense my code to make them reference one function. Here's an example of what I have:

```
Private Sub color_chart()

Dim chartIterator As Integer, pointIterator As Integer, _
    seriesArray() As Variant

For chartIterator = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    seriesArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                   Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values

    For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)

        ' ***** If percent is greater than or equal to 90, color is green. *****
       If seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 0.9 Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(0, 153, 0)

       ' ***** If percent is greater than or equal to 50, color is yellow. *****
       ElseIf seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 0.5 Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(239, 226, 42)

       ' ***** If percent is less than 50, color is red *****
       Else
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(229, 41, 41)
       End If

    Next pointIterator

Next chartIterator

End Sub
```

That's the code I want to use to reference to from all charts. But I get an error on the other ones, because the worksheet name isn't "chart" for all of them. How can I change this code so that multiple worksheets can call this function? Is there a way to make changes to a worksheet without explicitly using its name?

Comment: KalaNag's answer is (unlike what I thought from my original misreading - sorry!) along the right lines in that you could iterate over a numeric index for this. Alternatively, were you to run it from a button in each sheet (as I see done fairly often [sadly?]), `ActiveSheet` would then be usable to refer to whichever sheet was most recently used (i.e. to invoke the button).

Comment: This looks like VBA (in Excel) and not VB.Net (in Visual Studio). If that is the case, you should edit your question and replace the vb.net tag with vba. You should probably remove the basic tag in any case.

Comment: @blackwood the vb.net tag is correct, he can do all that using excel references inside his visual studio project.

Comment: @KalaNag He will have a hard time getting `Dim seriesArray() As Variant` to compile in VB.Net.

Comment: @blackwood you are right, that is vba and not vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Sheets" property is just a collection of worksheet items, and so it can be referenced by specific name or by its ordinal, like `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(0).Chartobjects`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822101.aspx

Edit to expand on your case, since you say you just took VB recently:

Use a For Each to iterate the worksheets collection, for example like this:

```
For Each wsheet As WorkSheet in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  wsheet.ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(239, 226, 42)
Next
```

Comment: ...and he can iterate the collection with a For Each without needing to know the names.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misinterpreted.

Comment: Ah! I see now. I was hoping there was a way to reference based on worksheet number. I just used a for loop with an integer counter to navigate through the worksheets. Thanks so much!